# Running an Airflow DAG every X minutes

Tags: python, airflow

I am using airflow on an EC2 instance using the `LocalScheduler` option. I've invoked `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver` and everything seems to be running fine. That said, after supplying the `cron` string to `schedule_interval` for "do this every 10 minutes," `'*/10 * * * *'`, the job continue to execute every 24 hours by default. Here's the header of the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import ds_dependencies

SCRIPT_PATH = os.getenv('PREPROC_PATH')

if SCRIPT_PATH:
    sys.path.insert(0, SCRIPT_PATH)
    import workers
else:
    print('Define PREPROC_PATH value in environmental variables')
    sys.exit(1)

default_args = {
  'start_date': datetime(2017, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0), #..EC2 time. Equal to 11pm hora México
  'max_active_runs': 1,
  'concurrency': 4,
  'schedule_interval': '*/10 * * * *' #..every 10 minutes
}

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_update',
  default_args=default_args
)

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For airflow versions >2.1 you can use `datetime.timedelta()` object:

```
DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_update',
  start_date=datetime(2017, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0),
  max_active_runs=1,
  concurrency=4,
  schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10),
  default_args=default_args,
)
```

Another cool feature for handling start_date is `days_ago`

```
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_update',
  start_date=days_ago(2, minute=15), # would start 2 days ago at 00:15
  max_active_runs=1,
  concurrency=4,
  schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10),
  default_args=default_args,
)
```

Comment: Nice! Definitely a more concise way to do this with the new version 

Answer (score 13):

[default_args](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/models.py#L2661-L2667) is only meant to fill params passed to operators within a DAG. `max_active_runs`, `concurrency`, and `schedule_interval` are all parameters for initializing your DAG, not operators. This is what you want:

```
DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_update',
  start_date=datetime(2017, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0), #..EC2 time. Equal to 11pm hora México
  max_active_runs=1,
  concurrency=4,
  schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', #..every 10 minutes
  default_args=default_args,
)
```

I've mixed them up before as well, so for reference (note there are overlaps):

DAG parameters: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html?highlight=dag#airflow.models.DAG
Operator parameters: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#baseoperator

Comment: makes great sense, totally missed that. thanks @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel, is it possible to read this schedule_interval from an external file/config? Or we have to assign the value.