# Airflow: Run DAG every minute

Tags: airflow

Hi I have my DAG parameters structured as so

`default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 9, 26),
    'schedule_interval': "* * * * *",
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}`

But I'm not seeing my Airflow scheduler scheduling these tasks a minute apart or anywhere at all. I have also consulted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689391/schedule-a-dag-in-airflow-to-run-every-5-minutes) but it does not seem to be working as well. Am I missing something when constructing my DAG?

Comment: Is the DAG enabled? When you go to the main page of the UI, there should be an on/off toggle by each DAG.

Comment: Is your scheduler running? Did you go through the documentation at https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#why-isn-t-my-task-getting-scheduled ?

Comment: Yes the scheduler is running and the DAG is enabled. I'm getting weird interval, not the every minute update as I expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this (and just started digging into the airflow code to try and verify) but you might need to pass the schedule interval into the DAG like so:

```
dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, schedule_interval='* * * * *', default_args=default_args)
```

I had tried to do it like you did and had no luck either. This seemed to work for me though I have `0 12 * * *` as my schedule interval.

Comment: Ah yes that should be it. I've explained this before in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46183148/1969152, but still managed to miss it!